# Angular Observable and subscribe with FormGroup

Tags: angular

I want to replace space with "-" before subscribe my form field. but i got error on subscribe.
ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <form [formGroup]="frm1">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" >
            <input type="text" formControlName="family">
            </form>
            `,

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 

frm1 : FormGroup;

constructor( fb:FormBuilder){
    this.frm1 = fb.group({
        name : [],
        family: []
    });     
}
ngOnInit(){ 
    var keyup =  Observable.fromEvent(this.frm1.get('family').value , "keyup")
              .map((data:string) => data.replace(' ','-'))
              .debounceTime(400);               
    keyup.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
}
```

Comment: any other idea?!

Answer (score 2):

You can watch for the changes in the input field by subscribing to `valueChanges`, which can be used with forms, then use `patchValue` to assign the new value.

So do something like this:

```js
this.frm1.get('family').valueChanges.debounceTime(400).subscribe(value => {
  this.frm1.get('family').patchValue(value.replace(' ', '-'))
})
```

and you are good to go! :)

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTkzHsNthDCgiStuMDF8?p=preview)**

Comment: As a improvement, you could put this control `this.frm1.get('family')` in a variable, like this: `const familyCtrl = this.frm1.get('family')`, so you won't have to call the `get` method all the time inside the `subscribe`. Also note that if you press spaces indefinitely (so fast) it doesn't produce the expected result, I'd recommend to change the replace to: `.replace(/\s/g, '-')` :) [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/h49aMf9hCm7Tna2Q3qck?p=info)

Comment: @developer033 Are you stalking me? :D :D Yeah, but you are completely correct! :)

Comment: It's because I'm seeing the newest active questions :) Sorry for that haha

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach:

```
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <form [formGroup]="frm1">
            <input type="text" #nameInput formControlName="name" >
            <input type="text" #familyInput formControlName="family">
            </form>
            `
@ViewChild('nameInput') nameInputRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('familyInput') familyInputRef: ElementRef;

var keyup =  Observable.fromEvent(this.familyInputRef.nativeElement , "keyup")
              .map((data:string) => data.replace(' ','-'))
              .debounceTime(400);               
    keyup.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: yes i did that before with @Viewchild but i already looking for a way base on formControlName